# How to extract string '1,000' in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

If I do `str.extract(r'^(\d{1,})')`, it will only return 1 in this case. Is any way to extract the string like 1,000?

```
    Name    Income
0    A      1,000
1    B      900
2    C      80
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean find the row where the string is '1,000'? Or extract an arbitrary number within a string?

Comment: @ALollz I want to extract them first and then apply pd.to_numeric to income column

Comment: Well, you can probably circumvent this whole problem by specifying `thousands=','` in whatever `pd.read_` function you are using, and your numbers will be read in properly as floats, or ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update, it seems that you don't want to extract digits, so much as you want to remove anything that *isn't* a digit, so that you can cast to numeric.  For this, we can use `str.replace`:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Income.str.replace(r'[^\d]', ''))

0    1000
1     900
2      80
Name: Income, dtype: int64
```

The above will cast to numeric without raising any errors.  If there is a chance that your numbers could be floating point, you could just add `\.` to the list of characters to not replace (Still would not fit every situtation, but it might work for your input).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but to extract 1,000, you would simply do

```
str.extract(r'1,000')
```